# Navbar Dropdown not expanding

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to integrate a Navbar with a Dropdown into my Angular Application. To make sure, everything's right, I've exactly copied the instructions found on the official [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/) page.

For some reason the menu won't expand: (a click seems to reload the page)
[image]

I have no clue where to look :-/

```
<!-- statisches menu anzeigen -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">

    <nav *ngIf="currentUser" class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/home">S.GG-Community</a>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- main app container: maximaler platz nutzen aus index.html -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems a problem because you are not using Angular Ng Module correctly. May be using [routerLink]="#" instead of href="#" could resolve this.

Why don't you consider using Angular Material Library? https://material.angular.io/components/menu/overview

It works great and easier to implement on growing apps.

Answer (score 0):

You must include `bootstrap JS CDN` link also in your `html` page just before the closing `</body>` tag in order to make the dropdown workable.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>



  <!-- Your Navbar Contenr --> 
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>





  <!-- These three script tags are required in order to make the navbar dropdown workable and many other functionality -->

  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```